# Can a subset of a group be "abelian" but not be a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It seems to me that it's likely the case that, if a subset of a group is abelian, it must, in fact, be a subgroup. But, consider the following.

Let $A$ be an abelian subgroup of a group $G$. Consider $A \cup Z(G)$ — call this union $K$ — where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$.

Then $K$ is clearly abelian. However, is it a group? Consider arbitrary elements $p$ and $q$ of $K$ (that $K$ is nonempty is clear).

If $p$ and $q$ are in $A$, then clearly, $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

If $p$ and $q$ are in $Z(G)$, then clearly $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

If, however, $p \in A$ and $q \in Z(G)$, then it is indeed true that $pq = qp$, but that such a product is in $K$ is not entirely clear (it would, indeed, be in the *centralizer* of $A$ in $G$, but not necessarily — it seems to me — in the center of $G$). That is, since $q$ is in $Z(G)$, it commutes with all elements of $G$ (including, of course, $p$); but it could certainly be the case that $p$ does not commute with all the elements of $G$, and so is not a member of $Z(G)$, and so we could say little about the product $pq$.

Comment: As you say, there is no reason why that product should be in the union, and for example the dihedral group of order $8$ gives an example where it can fail.

Comment: @ThePortakal The OP was considering the union of a subgroup with the center.

Comment: As another example of a subset of a group that's abelian but not a subgroup, just take any nontrivial abelian group $A$, and let $K=A-\{e\}$, where $e \in A$ is the identity.